# Redirecting a WP multisite URL to a subsite URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite installation with a base URL of `https://example.com`. Subsites have an initial URL of `https://example.com/forinstance`, which can be changed in WordPress to an alias of `https://forinstance.com`.

But I want to redirect all URLs from `https://example.com/caseinpoint` ALSO to `https://forinstance.com`. There's not a way to do that in WordPress, so I'm trying to do it in my `.htaccess` file. I can't get it to work though.

I've tried variants of:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^example.com/caseinpoint$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://forinstance.com [R=301,L]
```

But it always just goes to a 404 on example.com.

However, this DOES work for other subsites:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS_HOST} ^ejemplo.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://perinstanza.com [R=301,L]
```

So it seems to be something to do with the multisite. How can I redirect `example.com/forinstance`, please?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of the rules you posted will actually do anything since `HTTPS_HOST` is not a valid server variable. It should be `HTTP_HOST`, which represents the `Host` HTTP request header (hence the `HTTP_` prefix). ie. the *hostname* (or *domain*) being requested.

The `Host` header does not include the URL-path, which you are trying to match in the first rule.

Presumably you want to redirect the remaining URL-path to the same on the new domain. eg. `https://example.com/caseinpoint/<url>` should redirect to `https://forinstance.com/<url>`? You aren't literally just redirecting `https://example.com/caseinpoint` (missing trailing slash) to `https://forinstance.com/` (there is *always* a slash after the hostname) as you've stated?

In which case you can do something like the following at the top of the root `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing WordPress directives.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^caseinpoint(?:$|/(.*)) https://forinstance/$1 [R=302,L]
```

This also allows for an optional www subdomain.

The `$1` backreference contains the value of the first capturing subpattern in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. the URL-path *after* "caseinpoint/" (not including the slash).

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid any potential caching issues. Only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed it works as intended. You will likely need to clear your browser cache before testing.